# Get a list of jQuery dialog objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog, jquery-widgets

I have a jQuery dialog that loads its content via Ajax.

The view that has been loaded into the dialog then needs to attach methods to the jQuery dialog object's events.

Im not sure how to go about this though. I tried using `$("#myelement").closest("div.ui-dialog")` (which does work) but it doesn't permit me to hook into its `close` or `resize` events.

Is there a way (given the ID of the div that the dialog was originally created from) to access the original jQuery dialog object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your issue:

```
$("#myelement").closest("div.ui-dialog").dialog("option","close",function(){
    alert("parent dialog closed!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) : the "close event" real name is [`dialogclose`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close).
There is no event triggered on `destroy`.
There is, if you need it, a [`dialogbeforeclose`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose) event.

You don't need to go up to the `.ui-dialog` to listen for this event :

```
$('#myelement').on('dialogclose', function(){ ... });
```

If you want to call a dialog method, the syntax is :

```
$('#myelement').dialog('close');
$('#myelement').dialog('destroy');
```

Comment: Sorry, was needing `close` and `resize` events - not sure why I typed destroy! I have updated my question.